# Why does Eldon admit that Rachel is an Android after the final question

Tags: androids, do-androids-dream-of-electric-sheep

I'm quite confused after reading chapter 5. I have the following question.

Why does Eldon admit that Rachel is an Android after the final question? Why does he not insist that she is a human just like he did after the initial round of testing?

Is it because of regardless of whether she grew up on a spaceship or not the idea or a briefcase made of baby's skin is wrong?

Comment: If you have multiple question please ask a question for each one and refrain from asking multiple questions in one go.

Comment: @Edlothiad fixed.

Comment: I thought it was because he was a rich sociopath who wanted to rub Deckard's nose in it and thought he could get away with not only the crime of 'aiding & abetting' the importation to Earth of an android, but could also keep her safe. He was right on the first count, and though he died before achieving the second, Deckard himself stepped in and assured that.

Comment: @patrick_corrigan Welcome to SFF:SE :)